# Determine whether LIMIT has been applied in PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Consider an SQL query

```
SELECT * from Users LIMIT 10;
```

Is there any mechanism to know whether LIMIT has been applied.

> Eg:
>   1. If query returns 7 rows, it determines the rows retreived were less than limit. hence no futher limiting was required
>
> 2. If query returns 10 rows, there are 2 cases    a. original query itself returned 10 rows, hence we couldn't further limit the results
>      b. original query returned >10 rows and we limited the results.

We could have used

```
select *, count(*) over () from users limit 10;
```

which will insert the count into each fetched row.
But what if I don't want to know upper limit on my records.Just info on whether LIMIT is applied or not could determine whether next page is to be fetched or not

Comment: use `LIMIT 11` instead and just ignore the 11th row?

Comment: There's no way I'm aware of to ask PostgreSQL for the number of candidate rows, or whether it could've fetched more rows. Often it has no way to know that without actually fetching the rows.